# python - RE extract strings after keywords into list

Tags: python, regex

Have a string as follow

```
string = {"name":"Peter","datetime":"2000-01-01T23:59:59Z","value":"61.77"},{...}
```

the ideal output would be

```
output = [(2000-01-01T23:59:59Z, 61.77),[...],...]
```

right now im using regex, which is obviously wrong given my inexperience in re...

```
dt = re.findall(r"datetime":.*?(Z))
```

After that I will extract the date by numbers until it matches a Z.
Similar for "value".
Making into a list by zipping the two re.finall().

```
results = zip(dt, value)
```

The main thing im not sure about is the RE expressions, but feel free to comment on anywhere you see fit, thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean `string` is a string?

Comment: is it output from json or python dictionary?

Comment: Yes it is a string type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your `string` variable is a string type.

You can also use `literal_eval` from `ast` module, like this example:

```
from ast import literal_eval

string = '{"name":"Peter","datetime":"2000-01-01T23:59:59Z","value":"61.77"},{"name":"Peter","datetime":"2000-01-01T24:59:59Z","value":"68.00"}'
output = [(i["datetime"], i["value"]) for i in literal_eval(string)]

print(output)
```

Output:

```
[('2000-01-01T23:59:59Z', '61.77'), ('2000-01-01T24:59:59Z', '68.00')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a string that contains many such occurrences of datetime and value, here's a regular expression that should work: `"datetime":(.*?Z)`.

Another solution is to use Json if this string is a proper Json string. Python has a built-in json module that you can use.

This looks like part of an object though, a dictionary. If this is the case, you can just loop over the dictionary's keys and get the values directory.

Answer (score 0):

or you could use a comprehension. Iterating over content and filtering in one go:

```
string = {"name":"Peter","datetime":"2000-01-01T23:59:59Z","value":"61.77"},{"name":"Peter2","datetime":"2000-02-01T23:59:59Z","value":"61.77"}
findDateTime = "2000-01-01T23:59:59Z"
output = [(line['datetime'], line['value']) for line in string if line['datetime'] == findDateTime]
print output
```